How to make Discord Android app to stop using microphone when it's not active or closed?
I have a Samsung Galaxy J5 on Android 7.1.1. After being inside the "Voice channel" and after closing the Discord app, my status bar looks like this, and the sound is still transmitted.

How to make the Discord application only use the microphone when it's active? Or at least make Discord stop using the microphone when I close the application.

Welcome. Are you inside a voice chat room? Do you see an indicator on the upper-right corner of the screen that the microphone is being used by Discord? Finally, just in case, could you mention the device model and Android version?

Its old Samsung Galaxy J5 , Android 7.1.1

After being inside "Voice channel" and after closing Discord app, my status bar looks like: https://pasteboard.co/p8YyxMaljHf6.png
Sound is still transmitted :/

Ah, I see. Discord does indeed allow background streaming. Based on a quick test on newer Android, Discord should also display a notification about the VC that can be expanded by swiping it down, and there's a "Mute" button. Did you see the button? (This might work only as a workaround since it doesn't do what you actually asked)


Did you see the button?

Yes. But doing so is very cumbersome and unintuitive :/
